# ARkit How to get exact point of node from tap location

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have following code on tap gesture on sceneview

```
 let location = gesture.location(in: self.sceneView)
 let hitTestScene = self.sceneView.hitTest(location, options:nil)
 if let first = hitTestScene.first  {

  }
```

I am able to get node from `first`

What I want is Suppose I have wall node which is SCNPlane or SCNBox with very big height.

Now If User tap on particular location let say on half of node. I want to that point in that node. 
So the question is With `sceneView.hitTest` I can get node which tapped but I want the location in node. like where that exactly tapped.

So I can measure height from origin to tapped location

Any Suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution.

We can get position to the hit node with `SCNHitTestResult`'s  **localCoordinates** property

```
        let location =  self.centerImage.center
        let hitTestScene = self.sceneView.hitTest(location, options:nil)
        if let first = hitTestScene.first  {
           print("localCoordinates in tapped ndoe is" first.localCoordinates ) 
        }
```

Hope it is helpful to someone